# Filename and path extraction - multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a set of folders in a drive and need to extract the path and filename of all of the files who have similar names (i.e., `index_lms.htm` or `index*.htm`).  I need these to go into a csv file, which I will manipulate and use in a mass upload template. Is this possible through `cmd shell` or a batch file? (It's been a while since I tried writing these.)

Today the size of the task got worse....... I now have 1000 English courses, and translated versions in German, Turkish and Russian. So I really needed a batch solution to extract these pathnames - thank you.

One other issue arose in the the filename cannot have spaces and I see that all of them have multiple spaces in their filenames. Is this easy to edit as the paths/filenames are read?

Quick answer to Gung - the files are loaded into an LMS system and the target file for elearning is normally index.html or index_lms.html or index_html5.html. However the LMS also serves up documents (my current issue) in my case they are all pdf with a standard naming convention

Comment: My soulution would be `find [topdir] -type f > filename` and then grep through `filename` for what you want. In DOS/Windows, I think `dir /s [topdir]` does something similar. I might be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: What is your definition of "similar?" Do you have a specific list of names such as "index_", "test_", "dskspc_", etc.? Are you expecting the script to determine what is "similar?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch will iterate the given folders and recursively search them for any file beginning with index and create a csv with a header and the columns File, Path and PathFile.

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
( Echo "File","Path","PathFile"
  For %%A in (
    "X:\Test\"
    "Y:\Home\Customer\"
    "Z:\Users\UserName\"
  ) Do Call :Search "%%~A"
) > "%~dpn0.csv"
Goto :Eof
:Search 
For /R %1 %%B in (index*.htm*) Do Echo "%%~nxB","%%~dpB","%%~fB"
```

The output file will have the same drive, path and name as the batch file but the extension `.csv`

Comment: I just ran this set and I worked like a dream - perfect.  You are an absolute star!

Comment: If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

This will create file **out.csv**.  Substitute your own dir pattern match.

```
del 2>nul out.csv
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir/s/b c:\index*.htm') do <nul set /p =%%f,>>out.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it in PowerShell.

```
PS C:\src\t> type .\f2csv.ps1
$dirs = 'C:\src\t', 'C:\labs'

foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    Get-ChildItem -File '*.txt' -Recurse |
        Select-Object @{Expression={$_.FullName}; Label="filename"} |
        Export-Csv -Path '.\f2csv.csv' -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
}
PS C:\src\t> .\f2csv.ps1
PS C:\src\t> type .\f2csv.csv
"filename"
"C:\src\t\iosloginfo\lognextnum.txt"
"C:\src\t\t\file1.txt"
"C:\src\t\t\file10.txt"
"C:\src\t\t\file2.txt"
```